# componentWillReceiveProps will update the state only if i refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

Hello everyone can you please help me with this :

i am using react + firebase + redux

the last lines in the class look like this (the edit post page):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
  const posts = state.firestore.data.posts;
  const post = posts ? posts[id] : null;
  return {
    post: post,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  };
};

const mapDispatshToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    editPost: (id, post) => dispatch(editPost(id, post, ownProps.history))
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatshToProps
  ),
  firestoreConnect([{ collection: "posts" }])
)(CreatePost);
```

after that i have used the componentDidMount to get the post like this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const post = this.props.post;
    console.log(post);

    this.setState({
      title: post ? post.title : "",
      content: post ? post.content : ""
    });
  }
```

i have also used the componentWillReceiveProps :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { post } = nextProps;
    console.log(post);
    this.setState({
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  }
```

my ipnut look like this :

`<input type="text" id="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

the console always dispaly `null`

i did not succeed to get the state updated (the only way to see the update is by refreshing the page)

can you please help me,

thank you

Comment: You should not use componentWillReceiveProps, it is deprecated since version 16, and will be deleted in version 17. Use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` instead.

Comment: Hey Piotr, i've tried the `static getDerivedStateFromProps` but this function is `static` and it does not have an access to `this.state` . what should i do ?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` has two parameters: `props, state`. As you can see, first one is current props, and second one is current state. You should return new state in this method, so it looks like this:

`static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
let newState = {...state};
newState.foo = props.foo;
return newState;
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was fixed thank you everybody :

the solution : 
unstead of using this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    const post = this.props.post;
    console.log(post);

    this.setState({
    title: post ? post.title : "",
    content: post ? post.content : ""
  });
}
```

i have used the `static getDerivedStateFromProps` like this

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, state) {
    const { post } = nextProps;
    return {
      title: post ? post.title : "",
      content: post ? post.content : ""
    };
  }
```

thank you Piotr Szlagura

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be forgotten to call dispatch function in your code.
For example, like this : 
    this.props.editPost(id, post); // this will update data of your redux store.
and then you can fetch updated data from your redux store.

Comment: Hello J.Odrin, thank you for responding. i am not trying to call the editPost function here i just want to get the data from firebase to the form first.
and in my case the data is coming from firebase but it wont be updated live.
 the only way is to refresh the page

Comment: so, i cannot understand you, I think that some event needed for fetching data from your store, how will you define event to fetch data from your store? If you don't define any event in your component, componentWillReceiveProps func will never fire without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, use `componentDidUpdate` :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.post !== this.props.post) {
    const { post } = this.props;
    console.log(post);
    this.setState({
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you Mohammed Ramrami for responding, i did try the componentDidUpdate but it shows this error `Cannot read property 'title' of null` this means that the post did not update yet. I've changet the setState like this `this.setState({title: post ? post.title : "", content: post ? post.content : "" });` but this also did not work (Maximum update depth exceeded)